# python generator drop certain number characters

Tags: python, iterator, generator

```
def hide(iterable):
    for v in iterable:
        yield v

def strip_last(iterable,n):
    counter = 0
    for i in iterable:
        counter += 1
        if n == len(list(iterable)) - counter + 1:
            return 
        yield i

print(''.join([v for v in strip_last(hide('camaro'), 1)]))
```

I'm trying to define a strip_last function that could produce every value
from the iterable except for the last n values, which is like this:

```
camar
```

but it only gives me:

```
c
```

What is wrong with it???
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `'camaro'[:-n]`?

Comment: replace `i` with `n`: `i == len(list(iterable)) - n:` Also I don't think you need `counter` at all.

Comment: FWIW, you're referencing `strip_last` as `drop_last` in your `print` statement below

Comment: I don't quite get that. Can you clarify it for me please?

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `len(list(iterable))` you empty the `iterable` so you have no further elements to iterate over.

Either you can copy your iterable using `itertools.tee` for building your counter or you can take a simpler approach and build a list inside `strip_last` and iterate over a `slice[:-n]` of it.

**Edit**: Adding the code -

```
def strip_last(iterable,n):
    size, word = itertools.tee(iterable)
    counter = len(list(size)) - n
    while counter:
        counter -= 1
        yield word.next()
```

Comment: I'm thinking that you could as well get internally a chunk of size n (a simple for counter getting `iterator.next()` 1..n times and returning the chunks as smaller lists) that would prevent you from copying the whole iterator

Comment: if you make a list, you defeat the purpose `tee`, just make a list from the start or get the size from the iterable like `sum(1 for _ in size)` also add a check for negative counters

Comment: @Copperfield agreed. The list is messing with the whole purpose, the other way around is to count all the elements in size until `next()` raises an exception but either way we're getting what he wants :-P

Answer (score 0):

for a generic iterable you have 2 to options:

1)you can make a list of your iterable and then iterate over a slice of it

2)you can keep n+1 number of elements from the iterable all the time and yield one and ask for other and when you cannot have n+1 elements then you know that you are done

```
from itertools import islice #, izip
from collections import deque

def strip_last_v1(iterable,n):
    it = tuple(iterable)  #because tuple weight less than a list of the same size
    stop = len(it) - n
    if stop > 0:
        for x in islice(it,stop): #I use islice instead of it[:-n] because the later make a copy of the tuple
            yield x

def strip_last_v2(iterable,n):
    n = n+1
    stack = deque(maxlen=n)
    it = iter(iterable)
    for e,_ in zip(it,range(n)): #izip and xrange for python 2
        stack.append(e)
    while len(stack) == n:
        yield stack.popleft()
        stack.append( next(it) )
```